# JQuery on click event variable gets 2 values instead of one

Tags: jquery, events, button, click

So I have a button and I want to increment a variable when the button is clicked. But for some reason it will increment the variable twice when it should only work once:

```
var punkt = 0;
$(".check").click(function(){
    punkt = punkt + 2;
    alert(punkt);
});
```

So in the first click `punkt` is 2, then in a second click it will be 4, then it should be 6 but it alerts twice. First alerts 6, then 8 and the value that I take is 8 instead of 6

Comment: `punkt = punkt+2;` What do you think ?

Comment: I want to increment the variable punkt by 2

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where you have written click event. might be click event binded twice on same class.

Comment: Please post your HTML code, there might be problem with that, anyway @KrnRajput provided the snippet which works fine. Please edit you context.

Comment: well maybe my problem was caused because i had some click events in my js file. I solved the problem by putting the js code directly to html file.
It seams this way it wont load twice. Thank you all anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this will helpful for you

```js
var punkt = 0;
$(".check").off( "click").click(function(){
    punkt = punkt+2;
    alert(punkt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='check'> count </button>
```

Comment: no, it is not working, on third click the result should be 6 but it is still 8!

Comment: and it alerts twice, on fourth click it alerts three times and i get 10, 12, 14

Comment: Your snippet is working. It is my script that keeps having the problem even when adding .off method

Comment: please edit question and put your full code so i can help you

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code help solve it?